# What should i use when i am fetching values from database and convert to String , String.valueOf OR toString() OR (String) casting?

Tags: java, string, casting

I am fetching values from database and i want to convert those values to String

There are three ways 
Which one to use?
String.valueOf  OR  toString() OR  (String) casting ?

Comment: Definitely not casting, unless they're strings already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 have different behavior, so you should use the one that suits your needs:

- String.valueOf() will return the `String` "null" if you pass to it a `null` reference, while `toString()` will throw `NullPointerException` and casting will just return `null`.
- If the instance is not a `String`, casting will throw a `ClassCastException`. Therefore `toString()` is safer (as long as you are not calling it on a `null` reference), and if you call `toString()` on a `String` instance, it will simply returns `this`.

Without any prior knowledge regarding the type of the instance you wish to convert to a `String`, and assuming you don't want to get the "null" `String` in case of a `null` reference, I'd use:

```
Object input = ...
String value = null;
if (input != null) {
    value = input.toString ();
}
```

or

```
String value = input != null ? input.toString () : null;
```

Comment: Or : `String value = java.util.Objects.toString(input);`